# ckeditor - contentsCss not loading custom styles

Tags: css, ckeditor

I'm using `ckeditor` v.4.8.0 included in my project by `npm`.

My config looks like this:

```
CKEDITOR.editorConfig = function (config) {
   config.extraPlugins = 'stylesheetparser';
   config.contentsCss = '/static/ckeditor/custom/custom_styles.css';
   config.stylesSet = 'default';
   config.autoGrow_MaxHeight = 500;
};
```

The file is there and the path is correct, still I my DOM elements in the editor just have the styles defined in `contents.css`.

Any ideas what I might be doing wrong?

Comment: Just to be sure, have you checked in the browser dev console if the file is loaded properly (so the path is resolved correctly and you can see it in network tab)?

Answer (score 1):

CKEditor by default uses contents.css which is added via config property - contentsCss.

`contentsCss: CKEDITOR.getUrl( 'contents.css' ),`

https://github.com/ckeditor/ckeditor4/blob/cae20318d46745cc46c811da4e7d68b38ca32449/core/config.js#L287-L303

A possible cause could be, you are not passing proper CKEditor.config to the method - CKEDITOR.editorConfig.

**How to debug:**

1. check the network tab, whether contents.css is still loaded.
2. put the breakpoint before and setting the contentsCss and check for the value in the console.

> config.contentsCss = '/static/ckeditor/custom/custom_styles.css';

3. Access CKEditor.config while running the application and check whether the property contentsCss is properly set.

*You can get more details regarding the configuration:*
https://ckeditor.com/docs/ckeditor4/latest/api/CKEDITOR_config.html#cfg-contentsCss