# How to add custom styles

Tags: javascript, ckeditor

I can’t add my own style, when I reload the page in the browser my styles do not add

````
    CKEDITOR.addCss('a{color: inherit; text-decoration: none}')

    CKEDITOR.stylesSet.add([{
      name: 'My Custom styles',
      element: 'span',
      styles: {
        'padding': '10px',
        'border-radius': '8px',
        'background-color': '#6950ab',
        'color': '#ffffff!important',
        'display': 'inline-block'
      }
    }])

    CKEDITOR.replace('container');
  </script>```
````

Comment: i wrote correct variant but i have to use the CKEDITOR.stylesSet.add
    CKEDITOR.replace('container', <styles>);

Comment: // For inline style definition.
CKEDITOR.config.stylesSet = 'my_styles';

// For a definition in an external file.
CKEDITOR.config.stylesSet  = 'my_styles:http://www.example.com/styles.js';

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In a classic editor (with toolbar) you may set config.contentsCss

```
    CKEDITOR.stylesSet.add('myStylesComboBox',[{
      name: 'my span style',
      element: 'span',
      attributes: {
        'class': 'box1',        
        }
    },
     {
      name: 'my span2 style',
      element: 'span',
      attributes: {
        'class': 'box2'          
        }
    }]);

      var ContentsCss = [
'span.box1{padding:10px;border-radius:8px;background-color:#6950ab;color: #ffffff!important;display:inline-block}',
'span.box2{padding:10px;border-radius:8px;background-color:#6770ab;color: #ffffff!important;display:inline-block}'];


    CKEDITOR.replace( 'editor1',{
      stylesSet: 'myStylesComboBox',
      contentsCss: ContentsCss
    } );
```

Example:

https://codepen.io/edsonperotoni/pen/JjjvZxz

References:

https://ckeditor.com/docs/ckeditor4/latest/api/CKEDITOR_config.html#cfg-contentsCss

https://ckeditor.com/docs/ckeditor4/latest/api/CKEDITOR_config.html#cfg-stylesSet

Answer (score 0):

Please use the following rule while styling in CKEditor for specific use cases *(shared by CKEditor support)*:

1. Preview & Print

please change default styling either by changing the rules in  contents.css file directly or by providing a different file with CKEDITOR.config.contentsCss option https://ckeditor.com/docs/ckeditor4/latest/api/CKEDITOR_config.html#cfg-contentsCss

2. Export to PDF plugin:

please provide different styling using https://ckeditor.com/docs/ckeditor4/latest/api/CKEDITOR_config.html#cfg-exportPdf_stylesheets

OR  change default styling with CKEDITOR.config.contentsCss option https://ckeditor.com/docs/ckeditor4/latest/api/CKEDITOR_config.html#cfg-contentsCss or extended it with the CKEDITOR.addCss() https://ckeditor.com/docs/ckeditor4/latest/api/CKEDITOR.html#method-addCss.

*You can refer to the below link if you are having trouble loading the CSS file defined in the configuration - contentsCss:*
[ckeditor - contentsCss not loading custom styles](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48187386/ckeditor-contentscss-not-loading-custom-styles/)